# How to view a pop up box with jquery for many data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

My question, before I go further with how I did it, is: How can I make this work, and make it easier and better than what I have done?

I have a database with a lot of data, and I am viewing all these in a table. Each `<td>` has a `<div title="">` included, so that all who mouseover each `<td>` can see more information about that data item. The trouble is, that it's only viewable as a table on mobile devices. To create a hyperlink for a new page is difficult, because that takes the user away from a `<table>` with comparrision to just that one data information. So I was thinking to use jQuery UI. And was reading a little over the "Basic Dialog" option. I tried to put that into my script, but I see I have way too much data. So I created a file called jq_scripts.php. In there I have a script to create dialog options. But first I include it like this in the header:

```
<script src=\"//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js\"></script>
<script src=\"//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js\"></script>
<script src=\"jq_scripts.php\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```

Then in the script I have put this as a standard:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
    });

    $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
      $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
    });

  });
```

But since I have so many different dialogs, I need one #id to each button with unique information, so this is what I have as a script:

```
echo "\$(function() {\n";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $database WHERE type = 1");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    foreach($abo as $abo_vis) {
        $abo_vis = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '', $abo_vis));
        echo "  \$( \"#dialog_" . $abo_vis . "_" . $id . "\" ).dialog({\n";
        echo "    autoOpen: false,\n";
        echo "  });\n\n";
        echo "  \$( \"#opener_" . $abo_vis . "_" . $id . "\" ).click(function() {\n";
        echo "    \$( \"#dialog_" . $abo_vis . "_" . $id . "\" ).dialog( \"open\" );\n";
        echo "  });\n\n";
    }   
}
echo "});\n";
```

This creates a viewing file with 12583 lines!!!

In a `<td>` I have put this `<a href="#" id="opener_<?php echo $abo_vis; ?>_<?php echo $id; ?>">_DATA_</a>` and in the bottom of the viewing file, I have created this:

```
echo "<div id=\"dialog_" . $abo_vis . "_" . $id . "\" title=\"" . $abo_vis . "\">\n";
echo "<p>" . $dialog_info[$id] . "</p></div>\n\n";
```

This creates this file to be a lot longer than needed. And on top of that, none of my `<a href="#">` works. Actually, the `<div id="dialog...">` actually shows, while on the demo it was hidden.

Comment: You don't need one id per cell. Selectors in jquery are pretty powerfull and you can make a generic binding between cells and a unique dialog for all the table.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do that? @TCHdvlp

Comment: yep... Hope this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/dbaxmvw0/ You should also give a look to `data-attribute` to store data in each cell.

Comment: Thank you @TCHdvlp. That was truly a great way to answer. But as I have stored the extra information in a <div title="##">.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is the way you are calling it, instead of using IDs use classes:

```
echo "<div class=\"dialog_" . $abo_vis . "_" . $id . "\" title=\"" . $abo_vis . "\">\n";
```

Comment: Tried that, but no change. But what I'm really looking forward to, is a change in how many lines my script will have.